# C++ binary search for a class

Tags: c++, binary-search

I have a class and I want to implement binary_search (from  library) to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class T_value{
public:

    T_value(const int _timestamp, const string _value) :
        timestamp(_timestamp),
        value(_value)
    {}
    int get_time() {return timestamp;}


private:
    int timestamp;
    string value;
};

int main()
{

    T_value one(1, "one"),
    two(3, "two"),
    three(43, "three"),
    four(-1, "four");
    vector<T_value> v{one,two,three, four};

    cout << binary_search(begin(v), end(v), 3);
}
```

Is that possible? Should I overload '==' and '<' operators (tried, didn't succeed) or something else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You either overload `operator <` or you pass a custom predicate to `std::binary_search`. Both is possible, but you need to make sure the vector is already sorted _before_ invoking binary search.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? How is it not working? Maybe those could help you in figuring out what exactly you should implement ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you send an `int` as the 3rd argument to `binary_search`,
just an `operator<` will not be enough, because you need to 
support both `int<T_value` and `T_value<int`

The suggestion is to create a comparator class with the members:

```
bool operator()(const T_value& lhs, int rhs) const
bool operator()(int lhs, const T_value& rhs) const
```

and send an instance as a fourth parameter.

Furthermore, the vector should be sorted before `binary_search` is
invoked. You could do this with `std::sort`, but now you need to
support a 3rd type of comparison, a 3rd member of the comparator
class could do that, like:

```
bool operator()(const T_value& lhs, const T_value& rhs) const
```

The end result might look something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5fa11e7fe045bc6)

Comment: Thanx a lot, Danny! I wasn't aware of 'operator()' (contrary to 'operator+' or 'operator<') conception before. This absolutely works!
By the way, how do you know exactly which opeartors do you need to overload for particular algorithm ('binary_search', for example)?
Why do we add '{}' after 'Comp' ('Comp{}')? :)

Comment: [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) takes a [binary predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BinaryPredicate) which must implement the [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). All the algorithms document their arguments like this.

Comment: `Comp` is a type. `Comp{}` is a default constructed object of type `Comp`. All the algorithms that take function-like parameters want things with an `operator()` (pronounced "operator call")

Comment: I'd also be tempted add `using is_transparent = void;` to `Comp`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Although you just need to implement `operator<`. Also the argument to `binary_search` is mismatched and the container must be pre-sorted.

Link to working example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0343dd205abac6f2

**Operator less:**

```
bool operator<(const T_value& other) const {
    return timestamp < other.timestamp;//you may wan't another sort criteria
}
```

**Pre-sort container and binary_search:**

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
cout << (binary_search(begin(v), end(v), T_value(3, "not used") ) ? "found" : "not found") << std::endl;
```